# Shortcut behaviour changed after upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, 17.04, terminator

I have recently moved from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04. Everything works fine except one little annoying thing; back in 16.10, when I opened a terminal with Alt+Ctrl+T, the terminal windows popped up.
Now it remains on background and I have to click on the terminal icon on the dash to make it appears.

Do you know how to restore the 16.10 behaviour?

Thanks in advance,

Matteo

PS: I am using Terminator

Comment: It also changed the behaviour in groups. Different windows are now considered part of the same group. Now terminal index and sending commands to multiple terminals can cause issues because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another link about the issue I was trying to solve at https://answers.launchpad.net/terminator/+question/404487

It looks like apps now use dbus so they are running in the same process when launched multiple times. This changes the way windows are grouped and also that opening a new window does not automatically get the focus like you reported.

There are several recommendations in that link. For me the possible performance improvements gained by using dbus are not so critical so I disabled dbus for terminator. What worked for me to disable dbus was the following command:

```
# disable dbus
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'terminator -u'
```

You can check your current settings before with the following command in case you want to rollback the change:

```
# info useful in case of rollback needed, check it before disabling dbus
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec
```

Regards,
Jorge

Comment: Hi Jorge, thank you! That definitely solved the issue!